# JTree node editing path comparison always true

Tags: java, multithreading, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode, treepath

I've been working on a file server program for a while, and thus far I've been able to avoid posting something here for help. But I cannot find anything on my problem and I am very confused.

I've added a popup menu with the option to create new top level folder, which really just creates a node and, after its edited sends its name to the server to create the folder. While I've got all of the editing working correctly and have the upload working, I am having a problem.

I change the JTree to be editable when the folder is created, and a while loop that continues until that node is not the one being edited, at which point it removes edit-ability from the JTree.

```
public static void newTopFolder(){
    DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot(); //now we have the root
    DefaultMutableTreeNode newFolder = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("New Folder");//will change to increment for duplicates
    DefaultMutableTreeNode empty = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("< empty >");  //easier way to have empty folder, don't worry about it
    tree.setEditable(true); //sets to editable
    model.insertNodeInto(newFolder, root, root.getChildCount()); //adds folder to tree
    model.insertNodeInto(empty, newFolder, newFolder.getChildCount()); //adds empty to tree, not real file
    TreePath nfPath = getPath(newFolder); //so we don't call getPath extra times
    tree.startEditingAtPath(nfPath); //automatically selects folder to edit
    System.out.println(tree.getEditingPath().toString()+":"+nfPath.toString()+";"); //returns [\user\, New Folder]:[\user\, New Folder]; which shows the two are equal
    while(tree.getEditingPath().equals(nfPath)){//when nothing is selected null if nothing is being edited, and path to other objects if selected

    }
    tree.setEditable(false); //changes to node will have been committed and editing disable 
    sendFolderToServer(nfPath); //sends folder to server after formatting as a String used in new File(Paths.get(nfPath));
}
```

Unfortunately, the while check `tree.getEditingPath().equals(nfPath)` always returns `true`, thus it remains editable.

But I don't understand why it remains true, it clearly shouldn't. In case it helps/ changes anything, this is run in a separate thread (otherwise the while loop would stop the GUI from rendering)

So what should / can I do, is there a better way to do this, or at least one that works?

**UPDATE:**

While I haven't found a solution to the clear problem above, If I instead test for `tree.isPathSelected(nfPath)` That works fine and the tree is set to not be editable afterward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get editing path doesn't remove the variable of the path being edited... Therefore, after it's done editing the most recently edited path is still the correct path.

Instead using `tree.isPathSelected(path)` will work